# Mirror binary tree with private left and right subtrees

Tags: c++, binary-tree

There's tons of info on how to mirror it, but those assume that node->left and node->right can be modified, such as this function (not mine, copied from another website).

```
void mirror(struct Node* node) {
    if (node==NULL) return;
    else { 
        struct Node* temp; 

        /* do the subtrees */
        mirror(node->left); 
        mirror(node->right); 

        /* swap the pointers in this node */
        temp = node->left; 
        node->left  = node->right; 
        node->right = temp;
    }
}
```

I know there has to be recursion and a base case (basically the "do the subtrees" part) but I have no idea how to do the actual swapping since Node is a class with the left and right subtrees being private (can't change that).

For reference, this is the class constructor (there's no default constructor). I can provide more functions if they're important (there are accessor functions but no mutators). It also uses templates, hence the T.

```
Node(const T &x, Node *L = 0, Node *R = 0) : data(x), left(L), right(R) {}
```

I also made two other functions (treeHeight and countNodes), don't know if that's relevant. And I have to make a new tree to return, not modify the original tree.

---

---

*Note -* [I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1757805/francis-cugler) *did not want to provide this as an answer but wanted to inform the OP about C++ syntax*

You originally had this for your function:

> ```
> void mirror(struct Node* node) {
>     if (node==NULL) return;
>     else { 
>         struct Node* temp; 
>
>         /* do the subtrees */
>         mirror(node->left); 
>         mirror(node->right); 
>
>         /* swap the pointers in this node */
>         temp = node->left; 
>         node->left  = node->right; 
>         node->right = temp;
>     }
> }
> ```

In `C++` you do not need to use the keyword `struct` when declaring it as a `function-parameter` nor as a `declaration` of a `variable`. You only need it when you are writing the `declaration` to the `struct` or `class` itself. You can simply do this:

```
void mirror(Node* node) {
    if (node==NULL) return;
    else { 
        Node* temp; 

        /* do the subtrees */
        mirror(node->left); 
        mirror(node->right); 

        /* swap the pointers in this node */
        temp = node->left; 
        node->left  = node->right; 
        node->right = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit and appended it at the bottom of your original question to help you with the syntax for C++ structs and classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you write your own swap member function:

```
void swapChildren(){ 
temp = node->left; 
node->left = node->right; 
node->right = temp; 
}
```

This swaps the left and right elements.

Comment: This is homework, so I can't modify the Node header file. And I forgot to mention that I have to make a new tree, not modify the original tree (if that changes anything).

Comment: You could replace each Node with a new Node, in which you switch the left and right Node

Comment: I assume you mean like this: Node<T>* left = node->get_right(); Node<T>* right = node->get_left(); How would I link this back to the new mirrored tree (let's say the name is mirrorTree) though?

Comment: Not like that, more like:
node = new Node(node->data, node->RIGHT(), node->LEFT());
Oh, but I see that you can not modify the pointer of Node*, you would have to use Node**

Comment: I figured it out: Node<T>* mirrorTree = new Node<T>(node->get_data(), mirror(node->get_right()), mirror(node->get_left())); seemed to work for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, by the way. The code above is not modern C++, I suggest reading up on how to write modern C++ Code. There awesome books for that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/9654834